# React-Redux :TypeError : props.onSubmit is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to call the action creator add Product from the form Product component. I am not getting where I am going wrong. Can someone please help me out to solve this? I am new to redux so how can I achieve the solution so that when the form is filled the product should be added and the action creator gets called.

Here's the code :

---

### FormProduct.js

```
import { makeStyles, TextField, Grid } from '@material-ui/core'
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useForm, Form } from '../useForm'
import Input from '../../components/controls/Input'
import Select from '../controls/Select'
import * as productService from '../../services/productService'
import DatePicker from '../controls/DatePicker'
import Button from '../controls/Button'

const initialValues = {
    id: 0,
    name: '',
    description: '',
    quantity: '',
    price: '',
    dop: new Date(),
    category: ''
}

const FormProduct = (props) => {
    const validate = (fieldValues = values) => {
        let errors = { }
        if ('name' in fieldValues)
            errors.name = values.name ? '' : 'This field is required'
        if ('description' in fieldValues)
            errors.description = values.description ? '' : 'This field is required'
        if ('quantity' in fieldValues)
            errors.quantity = values.quantity ? '' : 'This field is required'
        if ('price' in fieldValues)
            errors.price = values.price ? '' : 'This field is required'
        if ('category' in fieldValues)
            errors.category = values.category.length != 0 ? '' : 'This field is required'
        setErrors({
            ...errors
        })
        if (fieldValues == values)
            return Object.values(errors).every((formValues) => formValues == '')
    }
    const { values, setValues, handleChange, errors, setErrors, resetForm } = useForm(initialValues, true, validate)

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        console.log('handleSubmit',props)
        e.preventDefault()
        if (validate())
        {
            props.onSubmit(values)
        }
    }
    return (
        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <Grid container>
                <Grid item>
                    <Input
                        name='name'
                        value={values.name}
                        label='Name'
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        error={errors.name} />
                    <Input
                        label='Description'
                        name='description'
                        value={values.description}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        error={errors.description} />
                    <Input
                        label='Quantity'
                        name='quantity'
                        value={values.quantity}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        error={errors.quantity} />
                    <Input
                        label='Price'
                        name='price'
                        value={values.price}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        error={errors.price} />
                    <DatePicker
                        name='dop'
                        label='Date Of Purchase'
                        value={values.dop}
                        onChange={handleChange} />
                    <Select
                        name='category'
                        label='Category'
                        value={values.category}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        options={productService.getProductCollection()}
                        error={errors.category} />
                    <div>
                        <Button variant='contained'
                            color='primary'
                            size='large'
                            text='Submit'
                            type='submit' />
                    </div>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Form>
    )
}

export default FormProduct
```

---

### AddProduct.js

```
import React from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import {addProduct} from 'redux'
import FormProduct from './FormProduct'

const AddProduct = (props) => {
    const onSubmit=(product)=>{
        props.addProduct(product)
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <FormProduct onSubmit={onSubmit}/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default connect(null,{addProduct:addProduct})(AddProduct)
```

---

### actions.js

```
import products from '../apis/products'
import {ADD_PRODUCT,LIST_ALL_PRODUCTS} from './types'
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid'

export const addProduct=(productDetails)=>{
    return async (dispatch)=>{
        const productId=uuid()
        const response=await products.post('/products',{...productDetails,productId})
        dispatch({
            type:ADD_PRODUCT,
            payload:response.data
        })
    }
}
```

---

### reducers.js

```
import {ADD_PRODUCT} from '../actions/types'
import _ from 'lodash'

const productsReducer=(state={},action)=>{
    switch(action.type){
        case ADD_PRODUCT:
            return {...state,[action.payload.id]:action.payload}
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default productsReducer
```

Comment: I think you don't import your action from `redux` but from the file you defined it, in this case `actions.js`. Can you try that?

Comment: I imported the add Product from the actions file  but I am still getting the same error

Comment: Which `props.onSubmit` is the issue? The one passed to `AddProduct` from the `connect` HOC, the one passed to `FormProduct`, or the one passed to the `form` element?

Comment: @DrewReese The HOC is passing in `addProduct`, not `onSubmit` and the HOC prop is also called correctly as `props.addProduct`, so definitely not the HOC from the code we're shown here.

Comment: @phry Oh, right, went a level too deep when searching for "onSubmit" uses.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a redux error, since `onSubmit` is a normal react prop you are passing in manually. Something might be going wrong there, but from these snippets it is not obvious what. But nothing redux-related.

Some words to your redux usage though: if you are learning redux right now, you are following an outdated source. Redux has changed siginificantly on the past two years.
If you follow the official recommendations, modern redux will **not** contain

- use of `connect` for function components (instead, use `useDispatch` and `useSelector`)
- hand-written string action types
- hand-written actions or action creators
- use of switch...case or immutable logic in reducers

Please, drop whatever tutorial you are following and follow [the official redux tutorials](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/index) instead. You will be writing probably only 1/3 of the code you are writing right now.

Comment: If you are you referring to the redux-toolkit then I agree, it's certainly less boilerplatey. I disagree on the recommendation to ditch the `connect` HOC as this allows you to write redux/state-management agnostic presentational UI components.

Comment: @DrewReese I'm quoting the official style guide on that: https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/#use-the-react-redux-hooks-api

If you want to write purely presentational components, you can still do so with hooks - splitting components up into "hooks" & "dumb" components. Slightly more code, but still a lot easier to learn for people used to modern React than working with HOCs. Most people just don't make that distinction any more though anyways (most components will end up with useState & useEffect), so enforcing it by default is really not a good idea.